# Is it ok to often use yield reutrn WaitUntil(() => condition) in Unity or architecture is my weak point

Tags: unity-game-engine

I see that I often get to usage of `yield return new WaitUntil(() => condition)` in Unity. But it seems like not the best solution. Any advices on how to avoid it or that is fine?

Comment: Why do you believe it is not the best solution? Can you provide a more concrete example where you think there might be a different solution that is preferred?

Comment: @RetiredNinja just I have background in web development and for me it doesnt seem deterministic and I decided to ask if it is the correct way of doing things in Unity)

Comment: Seems deterministic enough to me. But if the question is whether you should or shouldn't be using coroutines in the first place, I recently have been discussing it on [stack overflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248144/unity3d). You could also search for other threads on SO regarding coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be using `async` and `await Task.Delay().

Or even more optimized use `UniTask` plugin.